# Mapbox Flutter: Initial Camera Position Shows Incorrect Location

Tags: android, ios, flutter, geolocation, mapbox

I'm using [mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl), which is a Flutter plugin for access to Mapbox services. Application needs to display the initial camera position fed from user's current location acquired via [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin. On the Android emulator, setting the current location to coordinates for Ljubljana, Slovenia (around 46N, 13E) displays map of Republic of the Congo, which is obviously incorrect.

[image: Initial camera location which should display Ljubljana, Slovenia, but it insteads displays a map of Republic of the Congo]

The `MapboxMap` widget is built the following way:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String mapboxToken = 'XXX-TOKEN-XXX';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _acquireCurrentPosition(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) =>
            snapshot.hasData
                ? MapboxMap(
                    accessToken: mapboxToken,
                    minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(6.0, 15.0),
                    compassEnabled: false,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: snapshot.data,
                    ),
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Future<LatLng> _acquireCurrentPosition() async {
    Position position = await getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );
    return LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
  }
}
```

Method `_acquireCurrentPosition()` correctly acquires latitude/longitude combination, and was tested on Android emulator, iOS Simulator and even physical Android device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro). Error with the initial camera position persists even when using a different location.

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some workarounds, I managed to identify and fix the problem using the following steps:

First, drop the geolocator package and replace it with [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package, and explicitly declare location permissions on Android and iOS, via mentioning them in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and `Info.plist` respectively

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Shows your location on the map and helps improve the map</string>
```

Next, instead of setting the initial camera location via `initialCameraPosition` parameter, you can use the `onMapCreated` callback:

```dart
// This is how you'd build the MapboxMap widget
MapboxMap(
  accessToken: mapboxToken,
  onMapCreated: (controller) {
    _acquireCurrentLocation().then((LatLong location) {
      if (location != null) {
        controller.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: location,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }).catchError((error) => print(error));
  },
  minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(6.0, 15.0),
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(45.45, 45.45),
  ),
);

// Method that uses location plugin
Future<LatLng> _acquireCurrentLocation() async {
  Location location = new Location();

  bool serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
  LocationData locationData;

  serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return null;
      }
    }

  permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
  if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  locationData = await location.getLocation();
  return LatLng(locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude);
}
```

My personal recommendation is to change the minimum SDK version for Android to 23.